# iOS simulator not displaying labels from storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

iPhone simulator is not showing some of the labels properly. Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know how to fix it? I also noticed that if I drag the buttons too quickly, xcode would crash randomly...

Thanks

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue recently and it was a weird bug. For whatever reason, the x/y axis was off in what I was seeing in Storyboard. So the `UILabel` and `UITextfield` I had were being displayed behind my NavigaionBar. I adjusted the x/y values in the size inspector on the right side pane of Xcode and it worked perfectly. Those value should be an accurate representation of the placement of storyboard objects.

Not sure about the quick dragging, sounds like an Xcode issue that may be fixed by now.